# ServiceStack.Redis RedisTypedClient TTL

Tags: servicestack.redis

I'm using ServiceStack.Redis v5.10.4 and trying to set the TTL using the following code:

*Note:*
mClientsManager = IRedisClientsManager
ttl = TimeSpan?

```
await using var client = await mClientsManager.GetClientAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
var typedClient = client.As<Test>();
await typedClient.SetValueAsync(key, value, ttl.Value, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Reviewing the data in Redis, the TTL is set to -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Just a side note... I used the synchronous method and it works.  Also looking at this location, it appears the method is calling the wrong overload... If I'm looking at the right source.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.Async.cs

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed this typed API in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/b58dd1c17a00c3c0a85ca85313f48b6c7b645e59). This change is available from the latest v5.10.5 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Alternatively you can explicitly change the TTL for a key using this async API:

```
await client.ExpireEntryInAsync(key, ttl.Value, token)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix.